# Qt focusObjectChanged example?

Tags: c++, qt, slot

I'm looking for an example on how to process the QObject pointer received by the slot when a 'focusObjectChanged' signal is received.  I'd like to know how to identify the object that is getting the focus?

The documentation indicates that the pointer is to the focus'd object, but how do I know which?

I've tried analysing the pointer in the debugger but I don't see anything obvious.

Comment: Well you can see its objectName(), you can look at the metaObject() to get the classname and stuff like that if the debugger on your platform can't get the runtime type. What's the real aim here though, seems like it could be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: @JosephIreland, how do I get the object name, the slot takes once parameter, QObject* ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can determine the class and object name, widget properties...:

```
QObject::connect(qApp, &QApplication::focusObjectChanged, [](QObject *obj){
    if(obj) qWarning() << obj->metaObject()->className() << obj->objectName();

    QWidget* widget = qobject_cast<QWidget*>(obj);
    if(widget) qWarning() << widget->geometry(); // or other properties

    BaseType* baseType = qobject_cast<BaseType*>(obj);
    if(baseType) qWarning() << baseType->some_actions();

    Type1* type1 = qobject_cast<Type1*>(obj);
    if(Type1) qWarning() << type1->some_actions();

    Type2* type2 = qobject_cast<Type2*>(obj);
    if(Type2) qWarning() << type2->some_actions();
});
```

or compare the pointer with widget pointers  to find the widget you need:

```
SomeClassSlot(QObject* obj) {
if(!obj) return;
if(obj == m_mainWindows) ....
if(obj->parent() == m_table) ...
MyClass myClass = qobject_cast<MyClass*>(obj);
if(myClass) myClass->some_method();
}
```

Comment: Does this mean I have to compare the pointer with all the possible pointers that is can be?  I would have thought there was an easier way to get the correct pointer.

Comment: You can translete to Type or BaseType your object:
`qobject_cast<Type*>(obj);`

Comment: but how do I know what the type is from the QObject ?

Comment: `obj->metaObject()->className()` return class name.
qobject_cast return nullptr for other type